# Replace numbers with text

Tags: php, moodle

I get data for a user `table` in `Moodle`:

```
            $data[] = $view-look;
            $data[] = $view->tyres;
            $data[] = $view->insidelook;
            $data[] = $review->motor;
```

And the data is for the `status` in each column. Statuses are the same from `bad (1)`, `good(2)`, `very good (3)` to `superb(4)`.

Right now only numbers are being shown. How to show, instead of the numbers, the **bad**, **good** etc. for each column?

Comment: Show us what you have tried - A hint would be to use a `switch()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way

```
    $data = [1,1,1,2,4,2,3,3,1,3,3,2];

    $mapping = [1 => 'bad', 2 => 'good', 3 => 'very good', 4 => 'superb'];

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = $mapping[$value]; 
    }
```

You will get the same array $data with the text content instead of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the switch statement or if statements. Its really up to you. I don't know what variable you're using for the status so am assuming its `$status`.

```
switch($status) {
   case 1:
       $status_text = "bad"
       break;
   case 2:
       $status_text = "good"
       break;
   case 3:
       $status_text = "very good"
       break;
   case 4:
       $status_text = "superb"
       break;
   // Have a default value just in case.
   default:
       $status_text = "not set"
       break;
}

// Add it to the data array.
$data[] = $status_text;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a short solution, crate an associative array (symbol table), and get the text corresponding to each number

```
$statuses = array(
    "1" => "bad",
    "2" => "good",
    "3" => "very good",
    "4" => "superb"
);

$data[] = $statuses[$status];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use shorthand `ternary` `operator` for this.

```
$status_text = $status == 1 ? "bad" : ($status == 2 ? "good":($status == 3 ? "very good" :($status == 4 ? "superb" :"not set")));
```